# Unable to exclude an unused dependency

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am trying to exclude support-annotations from play-services-maps but does not seem to work. My dependency tree relevant to this is pasted below. Please let me know how I should add the exclude.

This is how I was trying to exclude.

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1',
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

This is the tree.

```
_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 25.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.0 (*)
```

### Added entire list of dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

Comment: can you post the whole gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in syntax.
It should be like this:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1')
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```